# How to pass function as an argument?

Tags: matlab

Im completely new to matlab and I cant seem to find any info about this.
How may I implement this?

```
function [R] = GetY(func,x)
R = func(x);
end;

example: getY(5x+2, 1)
R = 5(1)+2 = 7
```

Comment: what does func() do  ? if you 're calling a function within another you need to define what she does? and for matalb 5x+1 isn't a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`function_handle`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html):

```
function R = GetY(func,x)
    R = func(x);
end
```

...

```
>> GetY(@sin, pi/2)
ans = 
    1
>>
>> GetY(@(x) x.^2 + 4, 2)
ans = 
    8
```